# Time component of the four-velocity and the speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, vectors, velocity

If we write the four velocity of an object we have,

$\vec{u} = (c\gamma_u, \gamma_uu^x, \gamma_uu^y, \gamma_uu^z)$
Since $\gamma_u > 1$, we see that the $u^0 > c$, and it seemed so strange to me. Any ideas about how this is possible or what does it represent ?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with the 0th component of the 4-velocity to be greater than $c$.
If you check the definition of the four velocity for a massive particle, where $x^\mu$ are outside coordinates and $\tau$ the proper time of the particle $$u^\mu = \frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}$$
you can examine the 0th component, which is, as seen in your post equal to $c\gamma$, so (since $x^0 = ct$)  you obtain
$$c\gamma = \frac{dx^0}{d\tau} = c\frac{dt}{d\tau}$$
which you can understand as the time dilation formula $$\Delta t = \gamma \Delta \tau$$